# How can I debug MSMQ messages not arriving on a remote server?

Tags: c#, msmq

I have some code that sends a message to a remote queue.

```
var queue = new MessageQueue(queueName);
var message = new Message(queueMessage, new BinaryMessageFormatter());
queue.Send(message);
```

I've tried setting the queue using IP and hostname, it makes no difference:

> FormatName:Direct=TCP:1.2.3.4\Private$\my.queue
>   FormatName:Direct=OS:servername\Private$\my.queue

The messages appear in the outgoing messages queue (if I pause it)

When unpaused they're sent to the server.

There is a private queue set up on the server. There is nothing running that will take messages off the queue.

However, messages never appear in the queue on the remote machine. I don't know how to debug this problem. The queue is a private non-transactional queue.

Creating a local private queue and sending messages to it works fine.

Are there some logs or something I can look at to see what might be happening?

The status in outgoing messages shows state as 'connected' so there is no connection issue.

Edit:

The only logging I can find is in event viewer > microsoft > windows > msmq which has an entry that simply says "Message came over network" whenever I send a message via MSMQ. It has no other information.

Comment: A IIS application has very little access to the filesystem.  I would use a Network drive to send files and then have IIS read files from the Network Driver.

Comment: I'm not sending files, I'm sending serialized objects

Comment: I'd try a couple of things:

First, is your Queue transactional? If so, are you setting the appropriate flag in your calling code?

Next, on the webserver, in Computer Management->Services and Applications->Message Queueing->Message Queues->Outgoing Queues do you see any connections to the MSMQ server? Are there any errors?

Comment: Queue is not transactional, no errors, connection shows 'connected' in outgoing queues. Also going to edit question to add that I can see "Message came over network" in event log

Comment: Serialization output is a file.

Answer (score 3):

Solved, I added this:

`message.UseDeadLetterQueue = true;`

This made the server put it into the dead letter queue under `System Queues > Dead-letter messages`

Once this happened I could see my message and clicking it, it said 'Access Denied' under the 'Class' heading.

A quick google revealed that even though I had granted `Everyone` full access permissions to the queue, it was necessary to add `Anonymous Logon` and give that full access too in the security tab of the queue.

Comment: I'm surprised that Everyone doesn't actually include everyone...!